# Many DB queries in parallel - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have an API call that uses data from 10 underlying tables. They're unrelated (no joins), but are all used on the same UI view, so there's a single API call to get the data.

Problem is since EF Core only allows 1 query per `DbContext`, they're each awaited and run in parallel. Each database task takes 100-150 ms, so the total time is ~2 seconds. The thing is they're just get requests pulling from different tables for the view. There's no reason they can't logically be run in parallel.

The go to recommendation seems to be to be to make multiple `DbContext`s, but instantiating 10 of them seems ridiculous.

Others have said to do direct SQL, but again they're unrelated tables, and that also feels like a mess.

Comment: Why do not write one LINQ query? It does not matter that you do not have relations.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Can I pull data from that many tables with a single LINQ query?

Comment: Sure, but from question it is not possible to understand from which tables and what to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

If some of this data being pulled is for things like Lookup tables used to populate drop-downs and the like then you can mitigate some of this with caching such as having a Singleton LookupProvider that can expose collections of the lookups which check it's local cache (which can be set up to expire) and serve the cached values or load data into cache and serve that if the local cache hasn't been read yet or has expired.  Worst case this wouldn't necessarily run in parallel, but would mean that most calls wouldn't even need a DB call to retrieve some of the desired data.  Views that might alter that lookup data can instruct the LookupProvider to expire/reload their cache for that lookup at that point.

Otherwise, yes, a DbContext per parallel operation; It's not ridiculous. :) Inject a DbContextFactory or Unit of Work pattern so that the parallel operations can easily scope and dispose of their own dedicated DbContext instance to read the data needed. DbContexts are designed to be instantiated and disposed as needed. To cut down on time and resources, be sure to consider projecting to POCO classes (ViewModels/DTOs) where possible rather than loading and referencing detached entities.

Comment: No lookup tables. It's all actually user content of various types.